# How does Windows open a file which is present in a shared location?

Tags: windows, share

I don't know whether this is a valid question in this forum, but anyway, I'll just ask it here. There are some files which is present in a shared network drive, if I want to open them, then how does Windows open the file? What are the steps which it takes to open the file locally? Does it create a temp file? I want to know the internal working of Windows in these situation. It would be helpful if there are any reading material shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not create a local temp file when you access files on a UNC path or mapped drive letter.

Assuming we are talking about SMB/CIFS style shares, when the kernel receives a UNC path/handle the request is forwarded to the MUP (Multiple UNC Provider) which hands it off to the correct MPR/redirector. The request is then sent over the network to the other machine. SMB/CIFS is the most common protocol used these days and it is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cifs/d416ff7c-c536-406e-a951-4f04b2fd1d2b). This protocol allows you to perform functions similar to what you would do on a local volume, except the operations are performed on the remote machine.

The shell/Explorer also supports namespace extensions that map to network locations (FTP, WebDAV, Bluetooth etc.) but these generally don't expose files directly to applications. They might expose file content as a `IStream` but most applications can't handle that. In these cases a local copy of the file is needed. These implementations are fully in user-mode and are not compatible with the low-level file functions in the Windows API.